# Excel 2021: Filter a multidimensional range as a single column

Tags: microsoft-excel, range, file-filter

I have an excel file with 8k+ lines and 20 columns. I have already added a filter on the 9 first columns to display only the lines that fit my needs. The 11 remaining columns are a split of a single column where the categories are stored (catA, catB, catC, etc.). It means that each of these columns can contain the same data, but not on the same line.
For instance: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/trb8X.png)]

I would like to filter this range as I would for a single column. For instance, if I select "Analytics", I will display the first three rows, "Software", the last three.
Is there a way to do this in Excel (2021)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by BradR's answer:

1. Create a cell with a dropdown menu of all categories (in my example, this is cell `G2`)

[image]

2. Create a helper column with the following formula:

   =IF(COUNTIF(A2:C2,G$2)>0,"Match","")

(Adjust the ranges to match your file)

To use it, select the desired criteria in the dropdown menu, then filter on the helper column

[image]

Comment: Looks good. So there is no direct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Not an elegant solution, but a quick way of getting the data. Add a column that will provide the row number if it is the category you want then do a filter on the column for the Top or Bottom 3.  Of course the TOP would give you the last and the bottom would give you the first.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not looking for the top or bottom nth occurence. I am looking for the allthe rows that contains the value in any of the columns. Hope it is more clear.